# What are the risks when using StringBuilder and JPA native queries?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I need to create a native sql query and I plan to use StringBuilder for creating it.

```
StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
    sqlQuery.append("SELECT ");
    sqlQuery.append("b.\"id\", ");
    sqlQuery.append("b.\"title\", ");
    sqlQuery.append("a.\"author_name\" as author ");
    sqlQuery.append("FROM ");
    sqlQuery.append(":dbName b ");
    sqlQuery.append("JOIN ");
    sqlQuery.append(":dbName2 a");
    sqlQuery.append(" ON a.\"id\" = b.\"author\"");

    ObjectQuery query = objectManager.createQuery(sqlQuery.toString());
    query.setParameter("dbName", "Book");
    query.setParameter("dbName2", "Author");
```

Is it safe to use the append of StringBuilder? Will this not result in SQL injection from an attacker? Will attacker be able to append a part of query that will drop the entire database? Any suggestions?

I know this query is simple and can be written in a single string but I have bigger queries with if statements and loops that append more lines depending on parameters

I know the named query is safer but in my case I don't know what the query will be like until the last moment.

Comment: What's your reason for using a StringBuilder here? Your query can be written into one single String literal, no concatenation needed.

Comment: @Tom I have much bigger query with if statements that decides what to append. I put a short one for readability

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't matter whether you use String or StringBuilder, if you aren't using preparedstatement then it is vulnerable.

Comment: If you append a user input with no validation or if you dont escape user input carefully yes there might be possibility

Comment: You might want to look into CriteriaAPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the parameter values with  `Query.setParameter()` as in your sample code :

```
query.setParameter("dbName", "Book");
query.setParameter("dbName2", "Author");
```

you should not have SQL injection issues.

SQL injection happens as you concatenate yourself the user data in the created query.
But you are not in this case as the query created by the `StringBuilder` object is mastered totally by you and doesn't take any values from an external client.

> Is it safe to use the append of StringBuilder?

While the `StringBuilder` variable (beware : `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe) is created and manipulated in a method scope, it is not more or less safe than another solution.

It doesn't have any relationship with safety but as @HRgiger suggested, a good alternative would be using `Criteria` API.
It makes sense as you explain that the construction of your queries is very dynamic :

> I have much bigger query with if statements that decides what to
>   append

It would produce a much more maintainable and readable code.

Comment: @Octtavius you mentioned you use lot of if conditions, as david mentioned if you dont use user input this is the answer

Comment: @HRgiger, davidxxx What about the .append() method. Is there a better way to create a query or using StringBuilder is ok?

Comment: @Octtavius jpa2 criteriabuilder

Comment: thanks david and @HRgiger, well explained. just wondering: would there be any advantage using Criteria API especially if I am used with sql queries? I suppose it is not safer or faster. Probably it might be faster as it is not to be parsed on every method call as JPQL is. But if the queries varies a lot depending on parameters than there might not be much advantage of Criteria. I DON'T expect any comments/answers as it is a different topic but would be happy to hear your thoughts. :)

Comment: @Octtavius opposite, criteria is better fit for multiparameter search criterias and conditional where causes when you want to keep type safety

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is no risk to get SQL injections attacks, simply because of using `setParameter`, but you have to note that StringBuilder is not thread safe type.

Comment: Right. Though a local StringBuilder as above is okay, "thread safe."